# Sorting and limiting MongoDB queries by insertion order in a multi-process environment

Tags: mongodb

I am using MongoDB in a multi-process environment and I was wondering how I can sort queries by insertion order and limit it to documents inserted after a certain document. On a single process I can use the ObjectID but otherwise two ObjectIds from different processes in the same second might have the wrong order.

Example:

```
ObjectId("5236dc5c 88ee6f 2075 bd0049")
```

might have been generate by the process 2075 right before

```
 ObjectId("5236dc5c 88ee6f 2071 f35fb8")
```

by the process 2071.
Note that the timestamp part of both IDs equal (5236dc5c). This timestamp is given in seconds.

Comment: This would not be a reliable way to sort anyway since you would be sorting on process ID as well which in this example would mess up your sorting, better to house a separate field of type date

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To ensure insertion order one need an unique auto-incrementing sequence field. There are two recommended ways to implement this:

1. [Counters Collection](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/#auto-increment-counters-collection)
2. [Optimistic Loop](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/#auto-increment-optimistic-loop)

One thing to note which the documentation does not state: Only the Optimistic Loop does really ensure that insertion order equals sequence order. Still it's very likely for the Counters Collection approach, but it is not guaranteed by theory since the incrementation and the document insertion are two separate operations.

Comment: The first of those two links doesn't refer to anything like "counters collection" any more. Also, I haven't been able to locate the according documentation, though I admit that I'm not sure what to look for exactly.

Comment: Found it: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/

Comment: Thanks for the hint. The MongoDB docs have changed. I updated the reply to container working links.

Answer (score 11):

Using ObjectIds or a date field to sort on may not give you the results you are looking for. ObjectIds and dates in inserted documents are generated client-side, so if you are running with connections from multiple machines you will run into ordering inconsistencies unless the timing between your machines is perfect.

Can you provide more details on what you are trying to do? There are a few different ways to get the behavior you want from MongoDB, depending on why you need a list of documents inserted after a specific document.

If, for instance, you are trying to use that ordered list of documents as a kind of queue, you could instead use a [findAndModify](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/) command to fetch an unread document and atomically update a “read” field to guarantee you don’t read it twice. Each call to findAndModify would find the most recent document in the collection without a read field set to true, atomically set that field to true, and return your document to the client for processing.

On the other hand, if your use case really does require a list of documents in inserted order, you can exploit the natural ordering of inserted documents. In MongoDB, documents are written to disk in order of insertion unless changes in document size or deletions require things to move around. By using a capped collection, which is guaranteed to maintain natural ordering, you could feasibly get your list of documents by exploiting this. Please note there are several major restrictions that come with using capped collections, which you can find spelled out in [the documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/capped-collections/).

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer. I had to implement a service that tracks state changes in the system. So a client can contact this service to ask what has changed. Given some kind of identifier of your last "state" (the ObjectId of an entry in the state collection) you want to be able to retrieve all changes happened afterwards (all documents in the state collection that were inserted after the one with the given ID). I figured capped collections are the only way to solve this, even though it comes with several disadvantages like creating one state collection for every user.